# GMA 3150 change resolution permanent?

Tags: display, resolution, screen, intel, xrandr

I recently bought a Shuttle X35V2 with GMA 3150 graphics (great computer for the money). When i connect my monitor (native 1360x768) in only get two resolutions to choose from, 1024x768 and 800x600. I have understand that GMA 3150 with no problems can show resolutions up to 2048x1536 with no problem.

I have tried to use xrandr to change resolution to 1360x768 and it works very well.

But, I have not succed to set it to this resolution permantly, when I reboot it still set to 1024x768.

I also have a Asus Eee PC 1001PX with GMA3150. I have the same problem when i connect a monitor with high resolution to it

So, to my question:

How do I get 1360x768 permantly on my GMA 3150 graphics with Ubuntu 11.10?

Regards
Magnus

Answer (score 1):

Which graphic driver are you using?
also check this link,it might solve your problem http://newtoubuntu.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/ubuntu-10-04-fixing-the-monitor-resolution-with-xrandr/